# Typescript type description position in function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning typescript now.
While write some codes, I realize I don't understand the codes below.

```
const MainTable: React.SFC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const logKey = Object.keys(props.log[0]);
  const tableCells = (): JSX.Element[] => {
    return props.log.map((field, index) => {
      const element: JSX.Element[] = [];
      // here I will use map to push JSX element to element,
      // and return to parent map
    })
  }
}
```

Component `MainTable` is React stateless functional component, so I wrote the type after the variable name. However, for `tableCells` which is inside of MainTable component, the function returns an array with JSX.Elements, and the return type describes after `()`. I tried to describe the type after variable name so like `const tableCells: JSX.Element[] = () => ...` but lint complains about it.

So I'm wondering the differences between of them.

Comment: In addition to the answer (see basarat's response below) there's other issues with your code. Firstly, `tableCells` is just a function which returns an array of JSX elements, you need to actually call that function *or* return the JSX array straight up for the SFC to work.; Secondly, `map()` already returns an array, you can just return the element in the map function. The stub you have there, creating an array each iteration and pushing to it, won't work and is confusing. Finally, you aren't using `logKey` anywhere (though maybe you'll use it in the commented section later, if so nvm)

Comment: @Jayce444 Thank you for your comment. Because I have some conditions when I push each JSX element to ```element``` variable, and after that I need to wrap all of them with other component. So just made a function returns wrapped component, and logKey is also used other place as you mentioned :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `const tableCells: JSX.Element[] = () =>` ... but lint complains about it.

Because `JSX.Element[]` is not the correct type. The correct type is `() => JSX.Element[]` i.e. `a function that returns an array of jsx.elements`.

In use:

```
const tableCells: () => JSX.Element[] = () =>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Totally understood